# React Native JSON issue with YouTube Data v3 API call

Tags: react-native

I have a request pulling in from YouTube, to create a list of videos I want to display in a flatlist. I use the same approach across the application (calling WordPress, etc...), but when Im trying to achieve the same with the YouTube API (I've got the key setup etc..), it throws an error;

[image]

```
const Watch = ({typeOfProfile}) => {
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
let x = {foo: 11, bar: 42};

function playertype(val) {
   return 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/searchpart=snippet&channelId=UCa_6KiOjxm6dEC_mMRP5lGA&maxResults=20&order=date&type=video&key=xxxxx';
}

useEffect(() => {
fetch(playertype(typeOfProfile))
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    x = setData(json)
    })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);


const result = Object.keys(x).map(key => ({[key]: x[key]}));


return (
<View style={styles.body}>
 <View style={styles.topscroll}>
 {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
    <FlatList
      data={result}
      horizontal={true}
      keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View>
          <Text>
          {x.val}
          </Text>
      </View>
      )}
    />
  )}
</View>
</View>
);
};
```

Someone mentioned it could be an object being returned instead of an array, seems odd the json structure is the same as other requests I use this approach for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had to add brackets on the data property of the FlatList. So instead of

```
data={data}
```

I had to change it too;

```
data={[data]}
```

Code now;

```
<FlatList
        data={[data]}
        horizontal={true}
        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View style={styles.container}>
           <Image style={styles.imgyoutubeprev} source={{ uri: chkValue(item.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url) }} />
          </View>
        )}
      />
```